# Making web application go Public

Tags: jboss

I have my web Application deployed in jboss web server. It contains Servlets. Right now its url is **localhost:8080/MyWebApp** 
 I want to make it public so that the clients not in localhost can also access MyWebApp. I am new to this so I am not pretty sure about how to do this. I have browsed through many sites offering a domain but I dont understand where will my Server reside. 
Can I make my own System as Server and run jboss Server?

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding listening only on localhost, take a look at your startup scripts ; to make it listen on all the network interfaces you can use
   run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
   To listen only on a particular ip use
   run.sh -b 1.2.3.4
2. Ideally you do not want users to access http://some_server:8080/MyWebApp but something like http://some_server/MyWebApp. To do this you will need to setup Apache with mod_jk and proxy the requests to jboss. If you have never done this before, it might be challenging. But there are plenty of resources on the internet to help you perform this task.

Comment: I want this application to be available on the Internet. Will binding it to a particular IP make it accessible from anywhere in the Internet?

Comment: No. That will depend on whether your server is accessible from the internet or not. I am assuming this server is in your company's datacenter. You will need to work closely with your network team to figure out the details. But ideally, you do not want to expose jboss to the internet ; setup Apache on the proxy the requests to jboss and expose Apache to the internet while jboss resides in the internal network.

Comment: I want to know how to make my server accessible from internet. This is what I want to know basically.

Comment: Is tomcat installed on a server in a data center or is this your personal home pc ?

Comment: In that case 1. get it to run on the ip address 2. Find out your ip address on the internet (sites like myipaddress will tell you what that is) 3. Access the site using that ip address (this assumes of course that you do not have a firewall or that your router etc is not blocking incoming traffic.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way? What if my IP Address changes dynamically?

Comment: You can lookup DDNS to map the ip address to a name.

Comment: Can u tell me What has to be done exactly in detail. How will my ipaddress have a name in DNS server?

Comment: Lets see if I can summarize it in a few lines. The DDNS client is generally built into your router (eg Linksys). You configure Linksys to connect to one of the many sites that provide DDNS service. You need to have an account on one of these sites and select a DNS name. The client (on Linksys) then maps this name to the ip address that you specify. Even if the ip address changes, the mapping will remain the same